# Putting, POJO returned from mybatis, into HashTable degrades the performance as mybatis tries to load the pojo in its hasCode method

Tags: mybatis

I am using latest mybatis release i.e. mybatis3.2.2.

I have converted our old application which was on EJB CMP to mybatis, in which the newly converted mybatis code performance was much worse than the old code with EJB CMP.

Configuration settings of mybatis is as follows:

```
<settings>
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false"/>
    <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false" />
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
    <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="VARCHAR"/>
    <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="REUSE"/>
    <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25000"/>
</settings>
```

While analyzing performance issue through YJP profiler, I realized that `HashTable.put(<mybatis returned Pojo>, <value>)` methods were taking most of the time and seemed to be the only bottoleneck.

In the `HashTable.put()` method, we are putting Pojo returned from mybatis as a key. In which call, in turn it calls hashCode of that pojo, and from YJP I could see that in 'hashCode' method, it is calling `'org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.CglibProxyFactory$EnhancedResultObjectProxyImpl.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy)'`, which is actually seemed like calling jdbc drivers and loading this pojo properties and those are the once taking all of the time.

Can any please help and guide me as in why mybatis is trying to load the Pojo while putting into **HashTable** in its **hashCode** method? Also, how can we improve its performance if at all we can.

Also, I tried to override 'hashCode' & 'equals' methods into my Pojo and used/compared only primary key properties, but it seems to have no effect, it is still calling 'executor.loader' of ibatis and doing same thing.

Comment: Anyone can help guys? I am really looking forward to it...

Comment: Just a word of caution. `defaultStatementTimeout` takes `Seconds`, not `Milliseconds`.  You, probably, want to change its value to `25`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have finally found the solution.
The 'lazyLoadTriggerMethods' setting configures the methods that trigger lazy loading.

By default it triggers lazy loading for 'equals,clone,hashCode,toString' methods.
I configured this property in SqlMapConfig.xml and removed 'equals,hashCode,toString' methods from it, as:

```
<settings>
    <!-- below both entry required to achieve on-demand lazy loading -->
    <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false" />
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
    <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="VARCHAR" />
    <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="REUSE"/>
    <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25000"/>
    <setting name="lazyLoadTriggerMethods" value="clone"/>
</settings>
```

Note: You should only do this when you are sure that the hashCode and equals implementation does not use lazy-loaded properties or uses the accessor methods for reading lazy-loaded properties.

It dramatically increased performance.

Thanks,

Parag